# Pass list to http flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, http, dart

I would like to pass these kind of params to server

[image]

In `PageA`, when done button is clicked, I able to get this kind of output

```
I/flutter ( 4802): {material[0][name]: Cement OPC}
I/flutter ( 4802): {material[0][quantity]: 56}
I/flutter ( 4802): {material[0][type]: Bag}
I/flutter ( 4802): {material[8][name]: dd}
I/flutter ( 4802): {material[8][quantity]: 22}
I/flutter ( 4802): {material[8][type]: Box}
```

Here the code

```
 IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  for (var i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
                    if (_controllers[i].text != "") {
                      Map<String, dynamic> test = {
                        "material[$i][name]": nameLabel[i]
                      };
                      print(test);
                      Map<String, dynamic> test2 = {
                        "material[$i][quantity]": _controllers[i].text
                      };
                      print(test2);
                      Map<String, dynamic> test3 = {
                        "material[$i][type]": quantityLabel[i]
                      };
                      print(test3);
                    }
                  }
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.done))
```

My problem is how can I pass these output to http ? Is it using List or HashMap ? I'm kinda lost although it sounds simple...

Comment: so you're sure something like `material[8][type` is your _entire_ map key? I think you might want to refacfor this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look below it might be help you

```
List<String> names = ["jsbc", "snjc", "scnj"];
List<String> quantity = ["1", "2", "3"];
List<String> type = ["wqew", "dcvd", "dw"];

Map<String, dynamic> test = Map();
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      var data = {
        "material[$i][name]": names[i],
        "material[$i][quantity]": quantity[i],
        "material[$i][type]": type[i]
      };
      test.addAll(data);
    }
    print(test);
```

Output:

```
{material[0][name]: jsbc, material[0][quantity]: 1, material[0][type]: wqew, material[1][name]: snjc, material[1][quantity]: 2, material[1][type]: dcvd, material[2][name]: scnj, material[2][quantity]: 3, material[2][type]: dw}
```

Comment: Interesting. But how to loop through the map to  get the key and value?